# NSRegularExpression pattern for ICECAST data

Tags: ios, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to carve out ICECAST data from an audio stream using a NSRegularExpression, but I think I have a general problem with my pattern.

Here is my code:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"StreamTitle='(.*)';" 
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                         error:nil];

NSMutableString *messageAsText = [NSMutableString stringWithUTF8String:[messageAsRawData bytes]];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:messageAsText 
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [messageAsText length])];
NSString *message = [messageAsText substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
NSLog(@"Input: '%@', Output: '%@'", messageAsText, message);
```

Say the input is:

```
StreamTitle='Thomas Newman - Awkward Talk [The Horse Whisperer]';StreamUrl='';
```

I would expect to get this:

```
Thomas Newman - Awkward Talk [The Horse Whisperer]
```

but I get this:

```
Thomas Newman - Awkward Talk [The Horse Whisperer]';StreamUrl='
```

This is not NSRegularExpression related, because the regexp shows the same result if tested here:
http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Could anybody point me to the correct regexp?

Comment: BTW: The "ungreedy" option enforces the desired match... Looking for the ungreedy option in ios...
Sample PHP:
preg_match_all('/StreamTitle='(.*)';/iU', 'StreamTitle='Mychael and Jeff Danna - The Great Hall At Camelot';StreamUrl='';', $result);

Comment: OK, quick find and self answer: A little quotation mark makes the trick:

Instead of 
@"StreamTitle='(.*)';"

I need to use 

@"StreamTitle='(.*?)';"

Topic closed

Comment: You mean a little question mark?

Answer (score 2):

Try making the `*` quatifier lazy by following it with a `?` like this:

```
StreamTitle='(.*?)'
```